# How to approximate the size of an std::unordered_map in C++

Tags: c++, dictionary

It is said that an `unordered_map<int,int>` takes up much more space than a `vector<int>`. While I am completely aware of that, I would like to know how to get the *approximate* size of a single instance of an `unordered_map` in *C++*. For now, let's say that I inserted `n = 1000000` elements into it. I presume that the memory taken up is `n` multiplied by some kind of constant, I am, however, unable to find an accurate answer anywhere on the Internet.  
Here is what I'm doing. I'd like to *calculate* how much memory `u_m` uses, *without writing any code*. Is there a way to do that?

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

const int N = 1000000;
unordered_map<int,int> u_m ;

int main(){
     for(int i = 0;i<N;i++){
         u_m[i] = 123+i;
     }
     return 0;
}
```

If that makes a difference, I intentionally put `u_m` outside of `main`

Comment: [Why should I not `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) [Why is `using namespace std;` considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: You cannot calculate such things from first principles because the definition of C++ doesn't contain enough first principles. You can experiment with a specific implementation instead. Use a custom allocator that keeps track of allocated memory. Or you can study the code of a specific implementation and map out its memory allocation strategy, but that's way more difficult.

Answer (score 6):

There is no general purpose answer to this. The memory used can vary wildly based on the implementation. To be clear, `unordered_map` is not tree-based; it's typically implemented as an array of buckets.

But while the spec allows you to know how many buckets are currently in play (via `bucket_count`) and you can ask for the number of items in each bucket (with `bucket_size`), there is no way to ask how a bucket is implemented. Based on the various requirements of methods like `bucket_size` and `extract`/`merge`, it's likely a bare bones linked list (`bucket_size` is allowed to be `O(n)` in the size of the bucket, so it needn't know its own size directly; `extract` needs to be able to return a handle that can be transferred between `unordered_map`s, and `merge` is guaranteed not to copy or move when moving elements from one `unordered_map` to another), but the details of implementation are largely hidden.

There's also no guarantee on what is stored in the first place. It could be just key and value, or key, value and hash, or something else.

So while you can get basic info from the various `.bucket*` APIs, since the contents and implementation of a "bucket" is itself essentially unspecified, you'll never get an answer to "how big is an `unordered_map`" from any C++ standard APIs; you'd need to know the implementation details and use them alongside the `.bucket*` APIs, to get an estimate.

Answer (score 4):

An `unordered_map` is *not* a tree, it is a hash table.  It size is dependent on several things, both on amount you've inserted, but also on things like calling `reserve` to pre-allocate memory.  The specific settings of initial allcoation size and load factors are implementation dependent, so any guess you make will probably differ between compilers, and the order of operations that result in when and by how much the hash table resizes will differ too.